# Android WebView: how to scroll to an <a name=here> position

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm loading a self-created HTML page into a `WebView` in an Android app.

The HTML page contains a tag like `<a name="here"></a>` somewhere in the middle.

After loading that page, I'd like to be able to programmatically scroll to that position, as if I had clicked on a `<a href="#here">here</a>` link.

I tried with `loadURL` and with `loadDataWithBaseURL`, with every possible parameter combinations that I could think of, without success.

Note 1: I want to be able to scroll to that position after the page has been already displayed.

Note 2: I cannot use `scrollTo(x,y)` because I don't know the y position of that `<a name="here">` anchor within the page. If I could figure out the y position in the page of that `<a name>` tag, that would also solve the problem, but I don't know how to find that y value either.

(P.S. I'm loading the self-created HTML page by calling `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, _html, null, null, null);` where _html is the string with my HTML page)

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Inside `<script></script>` part of your HTML page, create a Javascript function to programmatically click a link on the same page:

```
function myFunction(){
   document.getElementById('myLink').click();
}
```

**2)** Instruct your HTML to run your Javascript function once the page is 100% loaded adding an **onload** event handler to your **body** HTML tag, this way:

```
<body onload="myFunction();">
```

**3)** Inside the **body** area of your HTML, anywhere, create an empty link just to have the functionality of a click to the anchor you want (as you suggested, the reference to your anchor is **#here**:

```
<a href="#here" id="myLink"></a>
```

**4)** Finally create an anchor at the desired position inside HTML:

```
<a name="here">HERE</a>
```

That's it. When the page is loaded it will go to the desired position.

If you want to try this before use... https://jsfiddle.net/vapx8rzk

Comment: Thank you, after studying your answer I have found a slightly different way to do it, which I'll post as a separate answer. Please note that I wanted to scroll to that position not right after loading the page, but later on, with a button click or on some other later event. But using javascript was the answer.

Comment: Note: for future readers who need to position the page at an inner location right after loading, the above may be a good solution, otherwise the next answer shows what worked for me.

Comment: On your terms: "**After loading that page, I'd like to be able to programmatically scroll to that position**". It perfectly sounds "scrooll once the page was loaded", I am sorry. You only said "scroll later" (and not just right after the page loading) now on your comment. Also on your terms "**position the page**", in my solution, is by scrolling, because the page can not have another option to go to some point instead of scrolling. My option is a fast, imediate scroll. If you wanted a fancy and delicate scroll, smooth and sweet for a cute and very sensible webpage, could explicited it before.

Comment: sorry if it was not clear. I mean that first I load the page, and then some time later, when some other event takes place, I want to scroll programmatically to a specific position within the page, corresponding to an HTML tag. Instant scrolling is fine. And I believe your solution work just fine. Being a beginner on the platform I managed to make the other solution work for me, and that's enough for now. I'm not accepting either solution yet as the answer, I'll do that when I'm more knowledgeable about the issue. And if others weigh in with suggestions, I'll follow that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, thanks to the above suggestions I found that calling "scrollIntoView()" works for me, like this:

1. Instead of <a name="here"></a>, I use an "id" attribute, like e.g.: <span id="here">
2. I call webView.loadURL("javascript:document.getElementById(\"here\").scrollIntoView()");